# Is there any rule defining what is anatomically required to climb (above all in the case of animals)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, animals

A tough question here : I saw a rather hilarious topic on this very forum about Pathfinder with elephants or horses climbing ladders due to a lack of rules saying they cannot.

I have been wondering something : **is there any specific rule that decides what surfaces or objects creatures can climb depending on their anatomy ?**

Quick examples from well-known animals : cats can climb trees like it's nothing but are helpless on harder surfaces, goats can climb almost any surface with asperities they can put their hooves on but won't climb a tree with a tall, branchless trunk, apes and monkeys climb trees and vines and anything similar with ease but nothing is sure about their ability to climb rocks, most vermins cling to any surface with the tiniest asperities...

So, is it up to the GM to decide or is there aything, either in the creatures' descriptions or in the core rules, that give details ?

Comment: Answer in answers, not comments please.

Answer (score 1):

### Pathfinder doesn't operate at that level of granularity.

Pathfinder, as well as the previous incarnations of D&D before it, is a system built to tell stories about adventuring heroes doing adventuring hero things.  As a result, it generally models adventuring hero things (like combat and humanoid movement) very thoroughly, and things that are unlikely to come up for the typical adventurer (like non-humanoid movement) less well.  Also, the system is at least partially built for playability and speed, which is hampered by the level of granularity you're asking for.

What this boils down to is this: Vertical surfaces have a Climb DC, and certain creatures have a bonus to Climb checks.  The only mechanical determining factor for whether or not a creature can climb a particular surface is the DC of the surface and the Climb bonus of the creature.

If you want to make house rules that further limit certain creatures to climbing certain surfaces, then that's your right as a DM.  However, I would heavily advise against such a rule.  All you gain from that kind of rule is a small amount of perceived realism, and what you lose is a significant amount of time whenever you have to look up whether a particular creature can climb a particular surface.

Answer (score -1):

There are rules for making your own handholds

> Make Your Own Handholds and Footholds: You can make your own handholds and footholds by pounding pitons into a wall. Doing so takes 1 minute per piton, and one piton is needed per 5 feet of distance. As with any surface that offers handholds and footholds, a wall with pitons in it has a DC of 15. In the same way, a climber with a handaxe or similar implement can cut handholds in an ice wall.

I would apply this to circumstances where a creature could not normally climb (a smooth vertical surface) but has claws or somesuch. Otherwise I would recommend just applying the climb DCs of objects as they come and remember that pathfinder is not a perfect simulation. If you balk at a goat (which has a +5 to climb) climbing up a knotted rope (DC 5) with ease you can invent your own system but it seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Answer (score -1):

### Yes.

You need at least two hands, and they must be free. The basic climbing rules (using the Climb skill) are assuming you are some sort of humanoid without a climb speed.  Taking that into consideration, you probably also need at least two feet.

> **You need both hands free to climb**, but you may cling to a wall with one hand while you cast a spell or take some other action that requires only one hand.  [PFSRD: Climb skill](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/climb)

It is important to note that in this circumstance, the "You" is the player character, not a GM's creature.

An ape, though it doesn't have the humanoid type, is a bipedal creature with opposable thumbs, a climb modifier, and could reasonably climb most surfaces with two hands.

In the case of a non-humanoid, non-bipedal, non-bimanual creature without a climb speed (such as a goat), the GM will need to get creative.

Comment: It is however worth noting that there are a variety of creatures without hands who have climb scores. The two free hands rule clearly applies to PCs but would be better applied to handless creatures as you need free legs (hooves) as otherwise goats could never climb anything (despite their +5).

Comment: "The basic climbing rules (using the Climb skill) are assuming you are some sort of humanoid without a climb speed."  Obviously, a GM needs to make a decision when it comes time for Billy to climb up the wall.  Can a goat climb a sheer rock face?  Probably, given what I've seen of goats.  Can it climb a flat wall with no texture, given only a rope?  No, because it has no hands.